# Error in the CLRS book for analyzing time complexity?

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

> 4.3-8 Using the master method in Section 4.5, you can show that the solution to the recurrence $T(n) =  4T(n/2) + n^2$ is $\Theta(n^2)$.

Wouldn't it be $\Theta(n^2 \log n)$?

Comment: I don't have any insight, but have you looked here for an error listing? http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrs-bugs/bugs-3e.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this is the [second case of the Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2) (in its generic form) with $c=\log_b a = \log_2 4 =2$ and $k=0$. Indeed, we have
$$
T(n) = aT\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + f(n)
$$
where $a=4$, $b=2$, and $f(n)=n^2$.
Setting $k=0$, since $f(n) \in \Theta(n^c\log^k n) = \Theta(n^2)$, we get $T(n) = \Theta(n^c\log^{k+1} n) =  \Theta(n^2\log n)$.